# Using my own template stored in database with CarboneJS

Tags: node.js

I working with **CarboneJS** in NodeJS, in order to generate reports.

This is the documentation : https://carbone.io/documentation.html#getting-started-with-carbone-js

To use CarboneJS is simple:

```
carbone.render('./node_modules/carbone/examples/simple.odt', data, function(err, result){
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('result.odt', result);
});
```

What I want to do, is pass my own template (Which it stored in database), lets call it for example **MyFileFromDatabase** so I can do something like this :

```
const MyFileFromDatabase = new Buffer (myFile);

carbone.render(MyFileFromDatabase, data, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      // write the result
      fs.writeFileSync('result.odt', result);
    });
```

What Im expecting to get : Carbone will render the document.

What I get :

```
complete erreur sendErrorHttp: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I don"t know if such feature exist, or should I go with other strategies? Like using Streams?

Answer (score 1):

For now, it is not possible to pass a buffer to the render function.
However, it is already a feature request and the team will probably work on it really soon. Here is the issue on Github: https://github.com/carboneio/carbone/issues/119

A quick alternative is to use the Carbone Render API, which gives you the possibility to pass the template as a Buffer or as a base64 String. You got 100 render for free per month Here is the documentation https://carbone.io/api-reference.html#carbone-render-api
A node SDK is available to call the API easily.

I will update the thread when the buffer feature is out!